# Number Scientific Format issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher, number-formatting

I seems that scientific format is not currently supported in cypher. Do you confirm? Would it be possible to add support to next releases?

At the moment, the following cypher query fails:
    CREATE (:Atom {`Name`:"H501", `Index`:501, `Partial Charge`:8.e-002, `Type`:"H"})

My issue is that I create cypher scripts from a third party software from which I cannot control easily number output format. Indeed, using format("%5.3f", charge) would return a string which would then be quoted in the cypher command.

Thanks
Pierre

Comment: If you don't use literal values but parameters instead, they would be used correctly. Also try to look into LOAD CSV with a CSV file as input in Neo4j 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j 2.1.1 has a `toFloat` function in cypher converting expressions to float numbers:

```
return tofloat("11.2e-4")
```

Comment: I'm still running Neo4j 2.0, but may upgrade soon. How can I use tofloat within the CREATE command?

Comment: yes, e.g. `create (x:Sample {xvalue:tofloat("11.2e-4")})
return x` works